# How can I display default face photo using the Facebook graph API?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using graph API. I need to show default human face picture. how can i show it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not twitter. I'll suggest you make it a bit elaborate, more than 140 characters.

Comment: I got user profile picture using https://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=large&width=160&height=160

Comment: but now i need the default face picture so how can i show it..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display a default picture in the case of no Display pic from FB.

```
    FB.api('/me/picture',function(response){
        var data={};
        if(reponse.data.url===null)
        {
          data=response;
          data.url='your default picture url'; //Hope this should work
          //You can use data object in your app now. 
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/), you will find plenty of examples there.

If its the profile picture you need, then this is the url you need to call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id_goes_here/picture
```

Comment: Add your facebook id in that url, and open it.You will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Ya, I got the user profile picture but if user not set the profile picture the default face picture is display. so i need that default picture id/ name. to show directly from Facebook.